# Initialize a double and its getter

Tags: java

What  benefits has the following?

```
private double pro;
pro = Double.NaN;
```

Why not make it

```
pro = 0.0;
```

the getter is:

```
public double getpro() {
    if (Double.isNaN(pro))
        somemethod();
    return pro;
}
```

Comment: 0.0 is a valid value and a real number, whereas NaN is not(Not a Number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `NanN` stands for "not a number," it is generally a hint that the number hasn't been initialized.

You could use `pro = 0.0;` and that would be fine, too.  I think that the issue is more of a style-thing.

Comment: I changed the initialization, but got bad results, is it because the getter?

Answer (score 0):

Because any operation on NaN results NaN. While operations with `0.0` may result as if `pro` is set to some value. While NaN may be used to represents that *`pro` isn't defined yet* as your case.

```
     Double d =Double.NaN;
     System.out.println(d*10);
     System.out.println(10/d);
     System.out.println(d/10);
     System.out.println(d+10);
```

results

```
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

while `d=0.0` would result something like

```
0.0
Infinity
0.0
10.0
```

Comment: In java variables of primitive types cannot be undefined (as are any value types, but in Java everything else is reference types). And NaN corner case that exists in floating point numbers doesn't really mean that a variable is undefined. NaN can be the result of valid computation(valid in terms of language definition). For example, sin(a/b) == NaN, if `a` is much bigger than `b`...
If you need to represent undefined state, you must use something else in addition.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in your case, `NaN` is a hint for the variable `pro` is not initialized and 0.0 is a valid initialized value.